# APIC send interrupt succeeds,but only once

Tags: assembly, apic

I 'm trying to send an IPI to myself.

Writing to APIC at position 0x310 and 0x300 succeeds (the interrupt is sent), but only once.

Next write does nothing, until I restart.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably because the interrupt handler isn't doing something it should do allow another IPI to be sent.

Comment: What sort of action should be taken then?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

I should write to the EOI register.

```
; Write it to 0xB0 (EOI)
    MOV EDI,[DS:LocalApic]
    ADD EDI,0xB0
    MOV dword [FS:EDI],0
```